# Extending base schema in JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, schema, jsonschema

I have a multiple JSON schemas, I want that there should be some properties that are common for all the schemas, instead of mentioning them in every schema I want to add them in the base schema JSON file.
I am rendering flows using XML, and this XML validates the JSON schema.

For example: there should be a isDisabled field in the base schema, and in all the other schema files it should be added as a property automatically.

Example of schema file:

```
{
  "name": "interactiveVoice",
  "uri": "http://some-company/schema/bpmn/ivr",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "description": "Properties for the voice file",
  "prefix": "voice",
  "xml": {
    "tagAlias": "lowerCase"
  },
  "types": [
    {
      "name": "voiceFilePlayerTask",
      "extends": [
        "bpmn:Task"
      ],
      "properties": [
        {
          "name": "taskType",
          "description": "This variable tells what type of task it is",
          "isAttr": true,
          "type": "String"
        },
        {
          "name": "taskName",
          "description": "hold task's name",
          "isAttr": true,
          "type": "String"
        },
        {
          "name": "isDisabledVoice",
          "isAttr": false,
          "description": "Checks if the voice file element is disabled",
          "type": "String"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "emumerations": [],
  "associations": []
}
```

I have tried adding isDisabled field in every schema file but it gives conflict that no two schemas can have same field, so I tried adding isDisabled field dynamically according to the task type i.e. for voice task: isDisabledVoice, for user-input: isDisabledUsrInput etc. In the above schema file I have added isDisabledVoice field similarly.